# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 104, column 109

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse an itunes xml library with python and element Tree, which is of this form:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Major Version</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Minor Version</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>156</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Stairway to heaven</string>
            ...
            ...
         </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key>
            <integer>342</integer>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Summer of 69</string>
            ...
            ...
         </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I tried to parse it with:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
fname = input('Enter file name: ')
stuff = ET.parse(fname)
```

BUT i get an error like this: "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 104, column 109". I searched through Stackoverflow before posting but i couldn't find any helpful to my situation post. Can anyone either post any relative post that i might have accidentally skipped or help?

P.S. I have tried changing the encoding to 'utf-8' but nothing happened. I have also tried:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
```

but nothing changed either.

Comment: Can you identify which line of the xml file it is telling you about? It may be correct and the xml is not well formed (missing a matching tag, etc)

Comment: Well, it shows also this in the error message:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tracks.py", line 50, in <module>
    stuff = ET.fromstring(fname)
  File "C:\Users\Left\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1334, in XML
    return parser.close()

which i guess is the 1334 line. but as long as i can see, there is nothing wrong there. at least with a first look.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong was the xml file indentation. I didn't know it actually plays a role, but i saved the xml file and opened it with Notepad ++ and worked.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer?
When people search non-answered question without accepted answers.
Thanks.

Comment: I have already done this, but it says: you can accept your own answer in 2 days.

Comment: I forgot about this, sorry.

Comment: Indentation? Really? Seems implausible to me.

Comment: Yes, i saved it in a wrong way and then after i opened it with notepad++ there was no indentation. I thought there wouldn't be any problem but i kept having the above error. After i tried everything i said i will try to save it again. This time i saved it in the proper way and after i opened the xml with notepad++ there was proper indentation. After running the script it played. Strange.